# El valor del tipo 'NSArray.Element' (aka 'Any') no tiene subscrips

Tags: ios, swift

Estaba pasando un proyecto de un tutorial de Swift 3 a Swift 5 y he cambiado una cosa de Swift 3 y me pone que 'NSArray.Element' se convierte en un Any que no permite poner subscripts. Este es mi código:

```
   (...) 
// MARK: Helper Methods
private func seedItems() {
    let ud = UserDefaults.standard
     
    if !ud.bool(forKey: "UserDefaultsSeedItems") {
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "seed", ofType: "plist"), let seedItems = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            // Items
            var items = [Item]()
             
            // Create List of Items
            for seedItem in seedItems {
                if let name = seedItem["name"] as? String, let price = seedItem["price"] as? Float {
                    // Create Item
                    let item = (name: name, price: price)
                     
                    // Add Item
                    items.append(item)
                
            }
             
            if let itemsPath = pathForItems() {
                // Write to File
                if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items, toFile: itemsPath) {
                    ud.set(true, forKey: "UserDefaultsSeedItems")
                }
            }
        }
    }
     func pathForItems() -> String? {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
         
        if let documents = paths.first, let documentsURL = NSURL(string: documents) {
            return documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("items")?.path
        }
         
        return nil
    }
}
     (...)
```

¿Podría alguien indicarme?

Después de hacer esto me ponía que

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me preguntaba como incorporarlo a mi código.

Perdón por este tipo de preguntas pero es que estoy aprendiendo.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un archivo `.plist` por defecto te dice que es un diccionario si lo abres como código:

```
click derecho->Open As->Source Code
```

La estructura del `.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Lo que debes hacer es pasarlo a un diccionario. En este caso utilicé el archivo `Info.plist`:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist"),
let seedItems = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath) { }
```

Para acceder al elemento:

```
seedItems["CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"]
```

El ejemplo del código:

```
if !ud.bool(forKey: "UserDefaultsSeedItems") {
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist"),
    let seedItems = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
                
        print(seedItems["CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"])
                
        }
    }
}
```

Imprime un Optional:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero como lo implemento para que el código lo imprima sin cargarme el código. Es decir, para mostrar los datos en el ítem.

Comment: Cambias el NSArray por NSDictionary y los valores imprimes directamente como te puse en la respuesta.